# How to create a linked list in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linked-list, nodes

I need to create a linked list, in which the input looks like this:

```
9
5
2.3
8
-1
```

And the output should be the elements of the list on the same line separated by a comma.

Basically I know that I have to create 2 classes, a class called "Linked List" that represents the whole list and a class called "Node" that represents each element of the list, but I'm completely lost and I don't even know how to "save" every element in a different node, I've never dealed with dynamic data structures before. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is your question how to create a linked list in Ruby, or how to print it? You should pick one.

Comment: Asking how to implement a linked list in Ruby is a very big question, probably too big for SO. Moreover, there is already a huge amount written on that subject. You should research the subject. You may wish to start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) and then google "Ruby linked list".

Comment: There is little point to implement linked list in Ruby - unlike C arrays, Ruby Array class can hold any number of elements, and implements all interface one could expect from a list, like adding elements to front and back, or traversing it (#push, #unshift, #each) - Array can be used in any list-based algorithm there is.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but in case someone is still interested in the subject, here is a post that shows how to implement linked lists in Ruby (in fact, is a series on "mastering" data structures in Ruby) https://medium.com/amiralles/mastering-data-structures-in-ruby-linked-lists-708347a30360

Comment: @AlejandroMiralles how do i implement this using a LInkedList https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52567549/algorithm-for-sequential-reward-points

Comment: @chrisgeeq I'm not sure if I would use a linked list... I guess a tree would do better in that case (as Olivier Melançon suggests on your post)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby stores `Objects` (instances of classes) by reference, and literal values (integer, symbols, etc.) by value. So if you want linked list of integers, you need to just wrap them into class.

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value
  attr_accessor :next
end
```

That will create class `Node` with `value` and `next` getter/setter methods.

In C terms, we will use `value` is Integer, and `next` is "pointer to Node". Note that we don't need to specify types beforehand, because Ruby is dynamic language. Also, no need for explicit "take a pointer to" operations, because, as I said above, Ruby will automatically pass objects by reference.

```
node1 = Node.new
node1.value = -1

node2 = Node.new
node2.value = 8
node2.next = node1
```

That will create `node2 -> node1` linked list.

Now, having reference to `node2` you can traverse all linked list:

```
node = node2
while(node) do
  puts node.value
  node = node.next
end
# Prints:
# 8
# -1
```

There is nothing broad or complex in your question. It's basic. Have fun with Ruby!

Comment: Minimalist yet comprehensive solution :)