# Algorithm for sequential reward points

Tags: algorithm

I want to write an algorithm to find the sequential reward points.
The inviter gets (1/2)^k points for each confirmed invitation, where k is the level of the invitation: level 0
(people directly invited) yields 1 point, level 1 (people invited by someone invited by the original customer)
gives 1/2 points, level 2 invitations (people invited by someone on level 1) awards 1/4 points and so on.
Only the first invitation counts: multiple invites sent to the same person don't produce any further points,
even if they come from different inviters and only the first invitation counts.
For instance:

Input:

```
A recommends B
B accepts
B recommends C
C accepts
C recommends D
B recommends D
D accepts
```

would calculate as:
A receives 1 Point from the recommendation of B, 0.5 Point from the recommendation of C by B and
another 0.25 Point by the recommendation of D by C. A gets a total score of 1.75 Points.

B receives 1 Point from the recommendation of C and 0.5 Point from the recommendation of D by C. B receives no Points from the recommendation of D because D was invited by C before. B gets a total score of 1.5 Points.

C receives 1 Point from the recommendation of D. C gets a total score of 1 Point.

Output:
`{ “A”: 1.75, “B”: 1.5, “C”: 1 }`

What should be the algorithm for that? I think Dynamic Programing has to be use here.

Comment: Are there retroactive points ? By example if `A->C, C accepts, B->A, A accepts`, does C have points?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon In your example, A can not accept the request from B because A is already a member of the reward program since A can send request to C

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Exactly.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: how on Earth did you manage to produce the `U+201D` double quotes `'”'`? Is there any programming language that would accept such quotes, or produce such quotes as output?

Answer (score 2):

This is simply an ancestors search in a tree. By keeping track of the depth, you know how many points to award.

#### Pseudocode

```
def add_points(accepter):
    depth = 0
    while accepter has an inviter:
        accepter.inviter.points += (0.5)^depth
        accepter = accepter.inviter
        depth += 1
```

This algorithm is *O(number of parents)* and since you need to traverse all parents to update, you know you can't do any better complexity-wise.

Comment: How can i implement this in ruby please?